# Contador decrescente com alarme

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Eu tenho um projeto onde eu início uma ação de 10min, por exemplo, e assim inicia um contador decrescente.

Esse contador será mostrado em uma tela pra gerenciamento (ele pode acrescer +1 minuto, como o *timer* do *widget* nativo do android).

Quando faltarem 15seg para terminar esse tempo, será tocado um alerta.
Ele pode ter vários tempos abertos.

Eu queria saber se com o `AlamManager` rola fazer isso de persistência desse tempo, pra ele poder fazer o gerenciamento de acrescentar +1minuto.

Obs: ainda não tenho nenhum código pra postar, é só uma dúvida de como posso fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O AlarmeManager "não foi feito" para esse tipo de processamento.

A própria [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), antecipando possíveis maus usos, refere:

> *The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.*
>
> **O AlarmeManager é destinado para casos em que você deseja ter seu código executado num determinado momento, mesmo se o aplicativo não estiver em execução. Para operações normais de temporização (tique-taque, intervalos de inacção, etc) é mais fácil e muito mais eficiente usar um Handler.**

O Android disponibiliza a classe [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) que permite agendar uma contagem regressiva, com notificações em intervalos regulares, durante a contagem.
No entanto, ela não se ajusta na totalidade ao comportamento que você quer, nomeadamente adicionar mais tempo ao tempo restante.

A solução será criar uma classe, do género da [CountDownTimer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java/), mas adaptada às nossas necessidades:

**CountDown.java** [(GitHubGist)](https://gist.github.com/rogamaral/75c8eafaae980c8c58309d2d4ec13b5b)

```
public class CountDown {

    //Interface a ser implementada por um listener
    public interface CountDownListener {
        //Chamado quando o valor de secondsLeft é alterado,
        //quando for decrementado ou incrementado.
        void onChange(long timeLeft);
        //Chamado quando o contador chegar ao fim.
        void onEnd();
    }

    private long fromSeconds;
    private long secondsLeft;
    private CountDownListener listener;
    private boolean isCounting = false;

    //Valor em milissegundos de um segundo.
    private static final long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final int MSG = 1;

    //Constrói o contador com o valor inicial de segundos.
    public CountDown(long fromSeconds){

        this.fromSeconds = fromSeconds;
        handler = new CountDownHandler(this);
    }

    //Inicia a contagem, a partir do valor inícial.
    public synchronized void start(){
        if(isCounting){
            return;//ou talvez lançar uma excepção
        }
        isCounting = true;
        secondsLeft = fromSeconds;
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG));
    }

    //Pára a contagem.
    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!isCounting){
            return;//ou talvez lançar uma excepção
        }
        isCounting = false;
        handler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    //Retoma a contagem.
    public synchronized void resume(){
        if(isCounting || secondsLeft == 0){
            return;//ou talvez lançar uma excepção
        }
        isCounting = true;
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(MSG), ONE_SECOND);
    }

    //Incrementa o valor do contador.
    public synchronized void increaseBy(long value){
        secondsLeft += value;
    }

    //true se o contador estiver contando.
    public boolean isCounting(){
        return isCounting;
    }

    //Guarda um listener.
    public void setCountDownListener(CountDownListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    //Método para formatar um valor em segundos em algo tipo "mm:ss" ou "HH:mm:ss".
    public static String secondsToString(long seconds, String format){
        return DateFormat.format(format, seconds * ONE_SECOND).toString();
    }

    private final Handler handler;

    //Handler para controlar o contador
    private static class CountDownHandler extends Handler
    {

        private final WeakReference<CountDown> countDownWeakReference;

        private CountDownHandler(CountDown countDownInstance) {
            countDownWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(countDownInstance);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            CountDown countDown = countDownWeakReference.get();
            if(countDown == null){
                return;
            }

            synchronized (countDown) {

                //Guarda o instante em que inicia o processamento.
                long tickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                //Se tiver sido parado sai.
                if(!countDown.isCounting){
                    return;
                }

                //Notifica o listener com o segundos que faltam para terminar.
                if (countDown.listener != null) {
                    countDown.listener.onChange(countDown.secondsLeft);
                }

                //O contador chegou ao fim, notifica o listener.
                if (countDown.secondsLeft == 0) {
                    countDown.isCounting = false;
                    if (countDown.listener != null) {
                        countDown.listener.onEnd();
                    }
                } else {
                    //decrementa o contador.
                    countDown.secondsLeft--;

                    //Obtém o tempo para o próximo decremento.
                    //Leva em conta o tempo gasto no processamento,
                    //principalmente o eventualmente gasto pela implementação
                    // do método onChange() no listener.
                    long delay = ONE_SECOND - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - tickStart);

                    //Se o tempo gasto for superior a um segundo, ajusta-o para o próximo.
                    //Se o tempo gasto no método onChange() for próximo ou
                    // superior a um segundo ele só será chamado no próximo.
                    while(delay < 0){
                        countDown.secondsLeft--;
                        delay += ONE_SECOND;
                    }
                    //Garante o término se o tempo for excedido
                    if(countDown.secondsLeft < 0){
                        countDown.listener.onEnd();
                    }else {
                        //Agenda o próximo decremento.
                        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

A classe permite criar um contador com um número determinado de segundos que, quando iniciado pelo método `start()`, fará uma contagem decrescente, até zero, notificando um *listener*, associado pelo método `setCountDownListener()`, quando o valor do tempo restante for decrementado ou incrementado através do método `increaseBy()` e quando o contador chegar ao fim.
É possível parar a contagem com o método `stop()` e retomá-la com o método `resume()`.

O nosso contador pode agora ser usado para controlar uma classe que encapsule o comportamento que desejamos ter durante a contagem.

Pelo que eu entendi, o comportamento que quer é:

- Apresentar o valor do tempo restante na tela.
- Accionar um alarme quando o tempo restante chegar a 15 segundos do fim.
- Poder adicionar mais tempo ao contador(já implementado no *CountDown*)

**CountDownBehavior.java**

```
public abstract class CountDownBehavior implements CountDown.CountDownListener {

    private final long alarmTime;
    private final String displayFormat;

    public CountDownBehavior(long alarmTime, String displayFormat){

        //Valor em segundos no qual deve ser chamado onAlarm().
        this.alarmTime = alarmTime;
        //Formato da string passada ao displayTimeLeft().
        this.displayFormat = displayFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(long timeLeft) {
        //Aqui é implementado o comportamento que queremos ter enquanto
        //o CountDown "conta".

        //Deve informar quando chegar a altura de accionar o alarma.
        if(timeLeft == alarmTime)
        {
            onAlarm();
        }
        //Informa o valor actual do contador, com o formato indicado por displayFormat.
        displayTimeLeft(CountDown.secondsToString(timeLeft, displayFormat));

    }

    //Metodos a implementar em resposta ao comportamento.
    protected abstract void onAlarm();
    protected abstract void displayTimeLeft(String timeLeft);
}
```

Quando associado ao contador, através do método `setCountDownListener()`, o contador chamará os métodos `onChange()` e `onEnd()`, toda a vez que a contagem é decrementada e quando chegar ao fim.

A resposta ao comportamento deve ser implementada nos métodos `onAlarm()` e `displayTimeLeft()`, numa classe derivada ou "em linha", numa classe anónima.

Exemplo de utilização:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private CountDown countDown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //Cria o contador com 10 minuto
        countDown = new CountDown(10*60);

        //Cria e atribui um CountDownBehavior ao contador
        countDown.setCountDownListener(new CountDownBehavior(15, "mm:ss") {
            @Override
            public void onEnd() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "terminou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onAlarm() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "alarme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void displayTimeLeft(String timeLeft) {
                textView.setText(timeLeft);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void startClick(View v){
        countDown.start();
    }

    protected void addClick(View v){
        countDown.increaseBy(60);
    }

    protected void stopClick(View v){
        countDown.stop();
    }

    protected void resumeClick(View v){
        countDown.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Antes de sair deve parar o contador caso este esteja a contar
        if(countDown.isCounting()){
            countDown.stop();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CountDown"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Iniciar"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="startClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mais 1 minuto"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="addClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parar"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="stopClick"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="retomar"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="resumeClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tentei utilizar este cod postado por vc mas não consegui :(

Comment: Por que não consegui?

Comment: ta danod uns erros estranhos pode ser alguma classe que não esta importando , vou verificar aqui como sou iniciante em android ainda m aperto por coisa besta

Comment: @ramaral muito obrigado pela sua ajuda! Código funcionou 100% aqui.

Comment: @ramaral Mas ainda tenho uma duvida, para esse tempo continuar contando quando o usuário fechar o aplicativo (e remover da lista do app recentes) só usando um service?

Comment: Sim, nesse caso terá de usar um *service*

Comment: @ramaral a implementação disso é facil? Eu nunca cheguei a criar um service ainda. Seria mais fácil eu, de alguma forma, decrementar de uma hora x para uma y toda vez que o cara abrir a activity, ao invés do service?

Comment: Depende do que quer fazer. Pode até não ser necessário usar um *service*, pode por exemplo guardar a hora em que o aplicativo foi fechado e comparar com a hora em que ele for novamente aberto e agir de acordo com o tempo que passou.

Comment: @ramaral A idéia é ter o contdown, e deixar o usuário gerenciar esse contdown e o contdown não se perder quando ele fechar o app e abrir de novo. Eu pensei em fazer dessa forma, salvando a hora que foi fechado, mas eu faria isso no onstop? Assim, toda hora que o cara deixasse em segundo plano o app ele salvaria, certo?

Comment: Depende, no código de exemplo que coloquei na resposta o contador só é parado no `onDestroy()`, mesmo que a aplicação passe para segundo plano ele continua contando, neste caso a hora deverá ser gravada no `onDestroy()`.