# Relógio Regressivo

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo. Normalmente em jogos existe um relógio pequeno que conta alguns segundos ao contrário, tipo de 10 a 0, e eu gostaria de colocar um no meu jogo.

Como eu posso fazer isso ?

PS: *Estou usando o Android Studio*

Comment: Use um [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151966/2541) também poderá ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a classe [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

```
new CountDownTimer(tempo, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))) + ":" + (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

            // o código abaixo mostra quantos segundos faltam em uma textview
            suaTextView.setTitle(hms);
            tempo = millis;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            suaTextview.setTitle("00:00");
            // executar uma ação quando o tempo acabar
        }
    }.start();
```