# Adicionar segundos a uma contagem regressiva - Android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de que quando um botao fosse clicado, 10 segundos fossem adicionados ao meu cronometro, mas não encontrei uma forma de adicionar valor ao CountDownTimer, aqui está o meu codigo.

```
private void contagemRegressiva(){
    new CountDownTimer(31000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv_tempo.setText("Tempo restante: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv_tempo.setText("Tempo esgotado");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: O CountDownTimer não tem essa funcionalidade. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151966/2541) onde usei/criei uma classe similar ao CountDownTimer com essa possibilidade.

Comment: Muito interessante sua resposta, mas será que não há uma maneira mais simples de resolver este problema?

Comment: Não sei se é mais simples mas há. Agora não posso, mas irei colocar uma resposta mais tarde.

Comment: Ok, irei aguardar, muito obrigado.

Comment: O que eu tinha pensado era cancelar o CountDownTimer actual e criar outro com o tempo restante mais 10 segundos. Não vou responder porque ao pensar na implementação verifiquei que ela é muito "feia". Note que da resposta que eu referi não necessita, para este seu caso, usar a classe CountDownBehavior. O uso da classe CountDown é idêntico ao da CountDownTimer. A diferença é que em vez de implementar os métodos abstratos tem de implementar um CountDownListener.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?